# Karma 4.4.1 and Braces 3.0.2 gives Unexpected token

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

After a rough migration from Angular2 to Angular8, I'm now reviewing all my karma tests that were working great before the migration.

For the version, I have:

- npm v6.11.2
- node v8.0.0
- karma v4.4.1
- braces v3.0.2

I don't know if it is relevant but I'm working with Jasmine and Webpack

Now, whenever I try to launch any karma command (even when trying `karma --version`, and even if there's obvious syntax errors in config files), I got :

```
path/to/node_modules/karma/node_modules/braces/lib/compile.js:39
      let range = fill(...args, { ...options, wrap: false, toRegex: true });
                                  ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/node_modules/karma/node_modules/braces/index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
```

I tried different command, nothing changed.
I tried different version either for karma or braces, nothing changed.
I also tried to ruin some config file, but it seems to fail before even trying to get it.

If anyone does ave an idea on how to make it work again, fell free to give a hint !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using Karma script from Git pre-push hook and I could resolve thanks to this [post](https://sigmoidal.io/automatic-code-quality-checks-with-git-hooks/)

Where say:

```
# magic line to ensure that we're always inside the root of our application,
# no matter from which directory we'll run script
cd "${0%/*}/.."
```